# Calling objective c method from javascript specified in remote html page

Tags: javascript, html, ios, objective-c

Hello I am working on application in which i am opening a menu in a webview in ios.

The menu is an html page. say menu have two options

1. Register
2. Login

I have following pages already developed.

```
1. http://example//menu
2. http://example//register
3. http://example//login
```

I am able to open menu page in a webview. now what i want to do is create a method in objective c like openpage(url) this function should open the url in webview.

The html pages works fine in Android, i want to get it working in ios.

the register onclick method is written as follow:

```
onclick="window.jsInterface.openPage('http://example//register'); return false;">
```

so I will require to create a interface named jsinterface and a method openpage into it. but I am not clear how to do it.

one more thing I want to know howdelegate method will identify the click of register and menu. that is if register is clicked then I need to open `http://example//register` page and if login is clicked then i want to open `http://example//login`.

Comment: [This](http://strongloop.com/strongblog/apples-ios7-native-javascript-bridge/) may help you. This tut discusses communication between objc and js and vice-versa.

Comment: @jnix can you send link ?

Comment: my above comment includes link. again you can refer Here -http://strongloop.com/strongblog/apples-ios7-native-javascript-bridge/

Comment: I have gone through that link but I am not able to identify how to identify click source in delegate method.

Answer (score 1):

you can use [webView:shouldStartLoadWithRequest:navigationType:](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIWebViewDelegate_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/UIWebViewDelegate/webView:shouldStartLoadWithRequest:navigationType:) delegate method for UIWebView

if you added delegate to UIWebView then above method gets called every time you click on any link in HTML page in webView . for more info. refer [THIS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5241187/uiwebview-link-click)

Comment: yes, but in delegate how can i identify if the register is clicked or login is clicked ?

Comment: check http://example/menu I want to open this page in uiwebview. and open further pages according the method specified on click of each menu

Comment: you can by simply parsing the link received in NSURlrequest in webView:shouldStartLoadWithRequest:navigationType: method you can get last part after // i.e. last part of http://example//login =>login and   last part of http://example//register => register hence you can get what you want.

Comment: I am trying this but when clicking on any menu the delegate method is not getting executed. do i need any other configuration for that ?

Comment: you have to set webview.delgate = youclassobject (youclassobject is class where you want to get notified for that delegate)

Comment: Most important I checked that URL there are ajax call on clicking controls on that page so [THIS](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5353278/uiwebviewdelegate-not-monitoring-xmlhttprequest) is more relevent to your solution