# uiwebview open tag img

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiwebview

Tell me please, I have an article that is introduced into the UIWebView. It has pictures, they are small and hard to see, I want to open by clicking the image at full size, so you can scale it and consider the details. At first I thought there need a JS module, but I was told that there are delegates from UIWebView. I can not find anything like it. Tell me what they are called, and please give an example.

Here's an example, when you click on the picture, it opens in full, and we can share the it.

[image]

Comment: You can't handle link inside webview

Comment: @RahulMishra and what if I spoke with the developers they are doing it, although using UIWebView

Comment: you can redirect from the link in UIWebView to a certain page when that URL is coded in HTML. else you can't interact with WebView Link...Have you seen any example of it

Comment: see this link hope it helps you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5241187/uiwebview-link-click

Comment: @user2759544 did you ever figure this out?