# Detect telephone tap, i.e.: <a href="tel:xxx"> on UIWebview

Tags: javascript, jquery, ios

I am trying to get a function to be called when a phone number is tapped on my UIWebView but this seems a little tricky.
The link is pretty straightforward, it looks like `<a href="tel:23231343">23231343</a>`

So All I need to do is simply emit an **`ajax`** to googleAnalytics so I can tell a phone call was placed. (I know it might not be actually placed, if the user declines, but I'd like to get the ajax nonetheless)

I was expecting to receive a call in the callback: `webView:shouldStartLoadWithRequest:navigationType`, but it doesn't fire.

Comment: did u try this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5241187/uiwebview-link-click ?

Answer (score 0):

Inject this script into the view:

```
(function(){
    window.addEventListener("click", function(event) {
        var element = event.target;
        do{
            if(element.href && element.href.indexOf("tel:") === 0){
                var request = new XMLHttpRequest();
                request.open("GET", "https://www.example.org");
                request.send();
            }
        }while(element = element.parentNode);
    });
})();
```

Comment: I am not sure, should this function be placed in document.ready? and, does this work for you? I tried using something similar in document.ready and it still did not fire

Comment: Realized what I did was very ineffective and won't work if elements are added later. I updated my answer to use event bubbling instead. You don't have to wait for anything before you add the updated script.